# Vectorizing a for-loop operation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, vectorization

I have an SDE I'm approximating by a numerical scheme using this code:

```
mu = 1.5;
Sigma = 0.5;
TimeStep = 0.001;
Time = 0:TimeStep:5;
random1 = normrnd(2,0.05,[1,500]);
random2 = randn(1,length(Time));
X = zeros(500, length(Time));

for j = 1:500
   X(j,1)= random1(j);
   for i = 1:length(Time)
        X(j,i+1) = X(j,i) - mu*X(j,i)*TimeStep + Sigma*sqrt(2*mu)*sqrt(TimeStep)*random2(i);
   end
end
```

How would it be possible to remove the outer for-loop and vectorize, so that at each time step, the first value is calculated for all 500 plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple, especially since `j` is only used for row indexing here:

```matlab
X(:,1)= random1;
for i = 1:length(Time)
    X(:,i+1) = X(:,i) - mu*X(:,i)*TimeStep + Sigma*sqrt(2*mu)*sqrt(TimeStep)*random2(i);
end
```

I tested both versions (Octave 5.1.0), and get identical results. Speed-up is about 400x on my machine.

General remark: Never use `i` and/or `j` as loop variables, since they are also used as imaginary units, cf. [`i`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) and [`j`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/j.html).

Hope that helps!